# configure: error: could not find a working compiler, (centos)

Tags: linux, configure, gmp, centos6.5

I need to build and install "GMP" but whenever i try to build it like:

```
 ./configure 0x2013prefix=/home/joe/local
```

this endsup with following errors

```
 configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

And here is complete output when i try to build GMP

```
checking build system type... pentium2-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... pentium2-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=32
checking compiler gcc -m32 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler gcc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... yes
checking compiler gcc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer has sizeof(long)==4... no
checking compiler icc -no-gcc ... no
checking whether cc is gcc... yes
checking compiler cc -m32 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler cc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... yes
checking compiler cc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer has sizeof(long)==4... no
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

**PLease help me,**

P.S: *I am using centos 6.5, And i am following http://www.linux-mag.com/id/5759/ tutorial to learn MPI, I have seen many question like this but not a single have helped me.*

Comment: The `0x2013` should be a regular hyphen (it seems the author mistakenly used a [Unicode dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)) but that seems unrelated to your immediate problem. Does the README file document C compiler requirements?

Comment: Thanks for your response, And no there are no requirment document

Comment: @tripleee you saved my day buddy, Please make write you above comment as answer, so that we can help others have same issue, 
Command was suppose to be ./configure 0x2013prefix-/home/joe/local

Comment: Huh? That makes no sense. The site you link to correctly says `--prefix=/home/joe/local` (and a bunch of other options you seem to be missing) although it does have the 0x2013 error elsewhere in the commmand line.

Comment: I am new in linux world,So do not know how this has to be done, but When i changed '=' to '-' it installed GMP, 
Can you please point out what i am missing as you said I am missing bunch of options

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was looking at the MPFR instructions just after. The instructions are obviously for someone whose login name is `joe` -- if your ID is `you` then your home directory will be `/home/you`, not `/home/joe`.

Comment: Yes i have used my name instead of joe

Comment: Note, for the principle, that when you get an error message that says: "see config.log for details", you should look at config.log, not go asking for help without telling anyone what is in that file...

Comment: @mshahbazm: I guess that it has something with `sizeof(long)==4` check failed for assumed `ABI=32`. Try to force `ABI=64`. Try to mess with `gcc` options from the output if they are supported in your config.

Comment: Unless you are specifically looking for a challenge, it's much easier to `yum install openmpi-dev` or whatever the package is called on your platform.

Comment: @tripleee yes it is easy to install, But if i just install MPI, GCC do not find its references.so GCC and MPI must be configured.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski could you please explain how can i force 'ABI=64'

Comment: @mshahbazm: Just append `ABI=64` to `./configure` invocation. For reference see GMP's manual (especially ABI section). The exact value for ABI might differ from platform to another. I have assumed common x86 architecture with 64-bit extensions in your case.

Comment: "if i just install MPI, GCC do not find its references" That's your problem and what you should be asking for help about, not re-compiling everything. Note that your tutorial recommends building things only if you are not root and cannot use your package manager.